# Why is it necessary to specify associated types in trait objects

Tags: rust

This code doesn't compile:

```
trait Trait {
    type Type;
}

struct Struct;

impl Trait for Struct {
    type Type = i32;
}

fn main() {
    Box::new(Struct) as Box<dyn Trait>;
}
```

The fix is to change

```
Box::new(Struct) as Box<dyn Trait>;
```

into

```
Box::new(Struct) as Box<dyn Trait<Type = i32>>;
```

I want to know why we have to specify associated types in trait objects. Wouldn't compiler look for `impl Trait for Struct` and find `type Type = i32`?

Comment: Yes, the compiler could infer that, but the rules are that `dyn Trait` always has to specify associated types.

Answer (score 1):

Think about this from another side. You *got* `Box<dyn Trait>`. How *can* you know what is `Trait::Type`? Well, you cannot. Trait objects function as type erasure. And since you could depend on this associated type you must be sure you can name it.

If you for example got `Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>` and want to get `Vec<Trait::Type>` (assume that `Trait::Type: Clone` for the sake of this example) how can you require all trait object's to have the same associated type? The answer is in your question. You simply must specify it. Without it you would pretty fast run in the wall.

Comment: Why do I "require all trait object's to have the same associated type"? The trait only includes type placeholders not actual types. Analogy: The trait only includes function prototypes not function implementations. Do you require all trait object's to have the same function implementations?

Comment: @TSK now imagine that the trait includes a function that returns `Trait::Type` (or takes a `Trait::Type` parameter). How would you use this function if the values have different types? And how would you use this function if you don't know what the type is?

Comment: @Jmb Each trait object can contain its associated types. Currently a trait object only has data pointer and vtable, but obviously you can add more to it if you want.

Comment: @TSK Rust is statically typed, so it needs to know all types at compile time.