# Trait object as associated type of a trait object

Tags: rust, associated-types, trait-objects, dynamic-dispatch

I wrote two structs that implement a common trait `Solve`. `Solve` has an associated type `Answer` with trait bound `Display`. I want the function `create_solver` to return a trait object of `Solve`.

I need help with writing the associate type `Answer = ??`.

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn main() {
    let solver = create_solver(2);
    
    let answer = solver.solve();
    
    println!("{}", answer);
}

fn create_solver(kind: u32) -> Box<dyn Solve<Answer = ??>> {
    match kind {
        1 => Box::new(SolverOne),
        2 => Box::new(SolverTwo),
        _ => unreachable!()
    }
}

trait Solve {
    type Answer: Display;
    
    fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer;
}

struct SolverOne;

impl Solve for SolverOne {
    type Answer = u32;

    fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer {
        3
    }
}

struct SolverTwo;

impl Solve for SolverTwo {
    type Answer = String;
    
    fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer {
        String::from("three")
    }
}
```

I tried setting `Answer = Box<dyn Display>` but that results in error.

```
fn create_solver(kind: u32) -> Box<dyn Solve<Answer = Box<dyn Display>>> {
    match kind {
        1 => Box::new(SolverOne),
        2 => Box::new(SolverTwo),
        _ => unreachable!()
    }
}

trait Solve {
    type Answer: Display;
    
    fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer;
}

struct SolverOne;

impl Solve for SolverOne {
    type Answer = Box<u32>;

    fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer {
        Box::new(3)
    }
}

struct SolverTwo;

impl Solve for SolverTwo {
    type Answer = Box<String>;
    
    fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer {
        Box::new(String::from("three"))
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<SolverOne as Solve>::Answer == Box<(dyn Display + 'static)>`
  --> src/main.rs:13:14
   |
13 |         1 => Box::new(SolverOne),
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type mismatch resolving `<SolverOne as Solve>::Answer == Box<(dyn Display + 'static)>`
   |
note: expected this to be `Box<(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)>`
  --> src/main.rs:28:19
   |
28 |     type Answer = Box<u32>;
   |                   ^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected struct `Box<(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)>`
              found struct `Box<u32>`
   = note: required for the cast from `SolverOne` to the object type `dyn Solve<Answer = Box<(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)>>`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<SolverTwo as Solve>::Answer == Box<(dyn Display + 'static)>`
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 | /     match kind {
13 | |         1 => Box::new(SolverOne),
14 | |         2 => Box::new(SolverTwo),
15 | |         _ => unreachable!()
16 | |     }
   | |_____^ type mismatch resolving `<SolverTwo as Solve>::Answer == Box<(dyn Display + 'static)>`
   |
note: expected this to be `Box<(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)>`
  --> src/main.rs:38:19
   |
38 |     type Answer = Box<String>;
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected struct `Box<(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)>`
              found struct `Box<String>`
   = note: required for the cast from `SolverTwo` to the object type `dyn Solve<Answer = Box<(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0271`
```

What should I set as `Answer =`  to make this work?

Comment: The associated types have to be the same across trait objects. See [Why is it necessary to specify associated types in trait objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74219030/why-is-it-necessary-to-specify-associated-types-in-trait-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associated type has to be the same for all types returned, and you have no such associated type. But you can create a wrapper type that using type erasure returns `Box<dyn Display>`:

```rust
fn create_solver(kind: u32) -> Box<dyn Solve<Answer = Box<dyn Display>>> {
    struct ErasedSolver<T>(T);
    impl<T: Solve> Solve for ErasedSolver<T>
    where
        T::Answer: 'static,
    {
        type Answer = Box<dyn Display>;

        fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer {
            Box::new(self.0.solve())
        }
    }

    match kind {
        1 => Box::new(ErasedSolver(SolverOne)),
        2 => Box::new(ErasedSolver(SolverTwo)),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the same problem as [making Clone object-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object), for which there's [`dyn-clone`](https://docs.rs/dyn-clone/1.0.11/dyn_clone/). You can do the same thing here by making another trait and a blanket impl:

```rs
trait SolveBoxed {
    fn solve_boxed(&self) -> Box<dyn Display>;
}

impl<T, D> SolveBoxed for T
where
    T: Solve<Answer = D>,
    D: Display + 'static,
{
    fn solve_boxed(&self) -> Box<dyn Display> {
        Box::new(self.solve())
    }
}
```

Full code: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8755ac96a2938cef7c026e1db4edabfa)

```rs
use std::fmt::Display;

fn main() {
    let solver = create_solver(2);

    let answer = solver.solve_boxed();

    println!("{}", answer);
}

fn create_solver(kind: u32) -> Box<dyn SolveBoxed> {
    match kind {
        1 => Box::new(SolverOne),
        2 => Box::new(SolverTwo),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}

trait SolveBoxed {
    fn solve_boxed(&self) -> Box<dyn Display>;
}

impl<T, D> SolveBoxed for T
where
    T: Solve<Answer = D>,
    D: Display + 'static,
{
    fn solve_boxed(&self) -> Box<dyn Display> {
        Box::new(self.solve())
    }
}

trait Solve {
    type Answer: Display;

    fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer;
}

struct SolverOne;

impl Solve for SolverOne {
    type Answer = u32;

    fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer {
        3
    }
}

struct SolverTwo;

impl Solve for SolverTwo {
    type Answer = String;

    fn solve(&self) -> Self::Answer {
        String::from("three")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works for this case. However, @Chayim's solution perfectly fits my requirements as that does not need a new public trait to be implemented, and keeping the already public methods as they were.